# Writing a perpetual program with Python to check validity of integers

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numbers, integer

I am a beginner in Python and I was trying to write a small program that asks the user to enter an integer that is greater than 0. The function should keep on asking the user for the number until it is valid.

I tried something like below, however I am getting the wrong results. Can you please help me understand my error?

```
num = input('please enter a number: ' )
n = int(num)
while n < 0:
    num = input('please enter a number: ' )
    if n >= 0:
       print('Valid number')
    else:
       print('Invalid number')
```

Is it possible to start the code without an input function? (like to start with num = int())

Thank You for Your Time

Comment: What does "wrong results" mean?

Comment: the second time you use `input` you bind the result to a name `num`. The while loop checks on the name `n`, it won't become `False`.

Comment: Edit your question to further explain the inputs, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the code not terminating, writing `Invalid number` all the time it's because you are not updating the value of n. You assigned it just once. The solution to your problem is as follows:

```
n = -1
while n < 0:
    n = int(input('please enter a number: '))
    if n >= 0:
        print('Valid number')
    else:
        print('Invalid number')
```

By the way you get rid of starting the code without an input function.

**Edit:**

As you just said - you want to keep the input reading despite passing an negative integer into the command line. This should help you accomplish this:

```
while True:
    n = int(input('please enter a number: '))
    if n >= 0:
        print('Valid number')
    else:
        print('Invalid number')
```

This loop will go forever until you exit the program lets say with `ctrl + C`. `while True:` is as you see an forever ongoing loop, because the `True` argument will never be false.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it. I was thinking though about running the program perpetually. This program you wrote will break when I feed a positive number. What if I want to keep on checking my numbers even though they are positive? Thanks again

Comment: I just updated my answer. It hope you meant it that way.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I meant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There's an error with the logic behind your code.

1. You firstly ask the user for a number and if he inputs a number which is greater than or equal to 0, the while-loop will never start (in your script: `while n < 0:`), which, I assume is fine, because the *goal* of your program is, as you said, to make *"the user to enter an integer that is greater than 0"*.
2. If the user inputs a number that is smaller than or equal to 0, the while-loop will start, but will never break because inside of it, the value of variable `n` never changes, only does the value of `num`.

This is an appropriate script considering that you want to *make* the user input a number greater than 0, and that you want to give feedback regarding their input.

```
n = None

while n <= 0:

    n = int(input('please enter a number: '))

    if n <= 0:
        print('Invalid number')

    else:
        pass # the loop will break at this point
             # because n <= 0 is False

print('Valid number')
```

The code has the user stuck in a loop until they write a number that's greater than 0.

**Another solution** would be to, inside the loop, check whether `int(num)` is greater than 0 and if it is, `print 'Valid number'` and do `break` to *stop* the loop; if it's not, `print 'Invalid number'` (though then the loop doesn't need to be defined by `while n < 0:`; rather by `while True:`.

Also, what do you mean by this:

> Is it possible to start the code without an input function? (like to start with num = int())

Please clarify this part.

Comment: Thank you dear for your clear answer. What I mean by that is, I understood that I replicated the input question(please enter a number). I wanted not to replicate. And if I dont write anything in the beginning, before the while loop, Python gives error. So I wanted to not replicate the input question.